# Download .apk or .jar file using HTML5 anchor tag download attribute

Tags: html

I am developing HTML5 based web application. In that web application i am trying to download a file from server. I have tested it on Chrome & Safari desktop browser. It is working fine on the desktop browser. But When i try to download the file using web application on the Android mobile using Chrome Browser and Android Default browser then the file gets downloaded but the extension of file and the name of the file is wrong (downloadApplication.bin) instead of (demo.apk).